# Lie algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Until now the only example of lie groups I have seen are subgroups of $GL_n$. Today I had the idea, that also $G=(\mathbb R^n,+)$ must be a lie group ($(\mathbb R^n,+)$ is a group with the differentiable group operation $+$). Is it right that the lie algebra of this lie group is $\mathfrak g = \mathbb R^n$ with the exponential map $\exp : \mathfrak g \rightarrow G: x \mapsto x$? What is the lie bracket of $\mathfrak g$? Is $[x,y]$ always zero, because $+$ is commutative?

Comment: Wikipedia to the rescue: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group (see first example in "Examples with $n$ dimensions")

Comment: Somewhat related (just for further information purposes): $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\times$ (cross product) is a Lie algebra. This isn't too surprising though. Suppose $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$, then $x\times y = (x_2y_3-x_3y_2, -x_1y_3+x_3y_1, x_1y_2-x_2y_1)$. You can view the action of $x$ on $y$ by a matrix multiplication: $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0&-x_3&x_2 \\ x_3&0&-x_1 \\ -x_2&x_1&0\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c} y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{array}\right).$$ Note the form that the matrix has. It should stand out as an element of a known Lie algebra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Solution 1

The left translation maps have the form $L_a:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n: x\mapsto a+x$. So $D L_a(x)=\operatorname{id}$ for all $a,x\in\mathbb R^n$ ($D L_a$ is the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map) of $L_a$). So the set of all left-invariant vector fields is the set of all constant vector fields $\mathfrak g=\{f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow T\mathbb R^n: f = \operatorname{const}\}$ (which is isomorph to $\mathbb R^n$ because $\mathfrak g$ is $n$-dimensional).

Because $X\in \mathfrak g$ is constant, one has $[X,Y]=\mathcal L_X(Y)=0$ for *any* given vector field $Y$.

### Solution 2

$(\mathbb R^n, +)$ can be embedded into $GL_n$ via $$f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow GL_n: (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto \left(\begin{matrix} e^{x_1} & & & & \\ & e^{x_2} & & \\ & & \ddots & \\ & & & e^{x_n}\end{matrix}\right)$$ $f$ is well defined because the determinant $e^{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n}$ is always positive and because of $e^{a+b}=e^a\cdot e^b$ the function $f$ is a group homomorphism.

Via $f$ one can show that $(\mathbb R^n,+)$ is isomorph to the set $D^+$ of diagonal matrices with positive entries on the diagonal. The lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $D^+$ is given by $$\mathfrak g = \{\dot\gamma(0): \gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow D^{+}\}$$ which is also $D^{+}$ (as one can easily show). Because $D^{+}$ is in the [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28algebra%29) of $GL_n$ the lie bracket is always zero.

Answer (score 7):

Yes and yes. (Exercise: exhibit $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a Lie subgroup of $\text{GL}_{n+1}$. If you get stuck, try the case $n = 1$ first.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have found an embedding of $(\mathbb R^n,+)$ in $GL_n$ (see my posted answer). Which embedding did you have in mind?

Comment: @tampis: there is an algebraic embedding; when $n = 1$ it sends $\mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and I'm too lazy to write out the general case.

Comment: Sir @Qiaochu Yuan, we can just use the fact $Lie(\mathbb{R}^{n})=T_{0}\mathbb{R^{n}}=\mathbb{R^{n}}$? Why we need to do a lot of calculations as comments above?