# Do real numbers with addition form a Lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Real numbers with operation of addition satisfy the criteria of a group. Zero acts as identity unity element, -x is an inverse of x because -x+x=0. But is this a Lie group?

Comment: Yes, embed $(\Bbb R,+)$ into $GL_2(\Bbb R)$ as closed Lie subgroup, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756365/lie-algebra-of-rn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we equip the reals with the ordinary differential structure, then it is true, since addition respects such structure.

Comment: So, the answer to my question is "No, because I didn't supply the ordinary differential structure". Thank you.